# Moving Target Defense implementation in context of SDN

Tags: ip

I need to demonstrate MTD for a project in context of SDN by writing logic for the SDN controller. The logic could be as simple as creating a new Virtual IP every n seconds. However, i would like some suggestions as to how something novel could be implemented. What factors other than time could be the basis for ip mutation.